# Trying to condense redundant IF statements, making a print command dependent on user input to choose list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

In Python...
In the following code, the user's input causes one of 5 lists to be printed.
Is there a way to make one line that is something like:

```
print(", ".join(EmpX_list))
```

Where "X" could be the value of the user input, emp_num in this case?
That way it is one line and not 5.

```
emp_num = int(input('Enter Employee Number:'))
if emp_num==1:
    print(", ".join(Emp1_list))
if emp_num==2:
    print(", ".join(Emp2_list))
if emp_num==3:
    print(", ".join(Emp3_list))
if emp_num==4:
    print(", ".join(Emp4_list))
if emp_num==5:
    print(", ".join(Emp5_list))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In other words, a single print command would be "constructed" in part by the user's input. The could be no 'if's at all in that case.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761, don't do this.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the warnings about variable variables. In my imagination: The variable in the print statement would be a dedicated one, for that purpose, and could be 'reset' to it's initial state immediately after printing. It is not changing the name of any list that is there, or any variable that would be used anywhere else... only building a print statement...In other words, one pass through this part of the code, then it can go back to some aribitrary value, or even not, since another pass through would give it whatever value it needed to print the desired list at that time.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense. How is that distinct from what I've linked? Where do these lists come from, why are they constructed like that to start with?

Comment: The lists come from user entry and are appended by those entries. I've read the link you sent before. I dont want to make a variable variable, I want a variable in a command. Print listX where X is a user input. Conceptually, it would be inserting the name of the list into the print statement according to the user's input. Who knows. Yeah my mind is a bit abstract. Thanks for the replies. EDIT: I guess the problem is 'addressing' a list with a number. If the user enters 4 for employee 4, what is to associate 4 with emp4_list. Hmmm....getting some ideas. More coffee.

Comment: You want a variable in a variable that's being _passed_ to that "command" (actually a function being called with the result of a method call). As shown below the same techniques (just use a dictionary) work here. And if you read the probable dupe, why is that not discussed _in the question_?

Answer (score 1):

You can print exact list without using if-else statements, but then you'll need to use python **dictionary**. Just store your lists with corresponding number as key value pair in dictionary and just access the element of the key user enters.

So your code will look like:

```py
Employees = { 1: Emp1_list, 2: Emp2_list, 3: Emp3_list, 4: Emp4_list, 5: Emp5_list}

emp_num = int(input('Enter Employee Number:'))
print(','.join(Employees[emp_num]))
```

Hope this answers your question. You can also refer the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373185/7212543) to the question jonrsharpe mentioned in comment.

Comment: `emp_num.get(emp_num)` doesn't really make sense... Please test your code before posting it!

Comment: ohh damnn! sorry mate, posted wrong variable name in hurry.

Comment: Note that it would be much better to use `Employes[emp_num]`. In case the number is invalid, this would immediately raise an explicit `KeyError`. `Employees.get(emp_num)` would return `None` in this case, causing `join` to fail with a less explicit `TypeError: can only join an iterable`

Comment: Yeah right, even giving default value to get method seems better option

Comment: If I request Employee number 10 and silently get the info of Employee 1, I would not be so happy... Better to fail loud than push wrong data further...

Comment: A default value is most likely _worse_, ["Errors should never pass silently."](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python)

Comment: Can't deny that! Better leave error handling on OP than providing false value. Will refactor the answer for same